# C# FtpWebRequest UploadFile, auto save when network interrupts

Tags: .net, file-upload, large-files, ftpwebrequest

When I write a tool to upload big file(1-2GB), using ".Net FtpWebRequest".
This is part of my code:

```
FtpWebRequest reqFtp = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fileUri);

reqFtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_ftpUserName, _ftpPassWord);
reqFtp.KeepAlive = false;
reqFtp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
reqFtp.UseBinary = true;
reqFtp.ContentLength = fileInf.Length;

const int buffLength = 2048;
byte[] buff = new byte[buffLength];
FileStream fs = fileInf.OpenRead();
Stream strm = reqFtp.GetRequestStream();
double totalLength = Convert.ToDouble((fs.Length + 0.0) / 1024 / 1024);
try
{
    int contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);
    double uploadLength = (contentLen + 0.0) / 1024 / 1024;
    double percentage = 0.0;
    while (contentLen != 0 && !(panel.Stop))
    {
        percentage = uploadLength*100/totalLength;
        if (panel.ProgressBar.InvokeRequired)
        {
            UpdateProcessBarDelegate d = UpdateProgressBarValue;
            panel.ProgressBar.Invoke(d, panel.ProgressBar, (int)percentage);
        }
        else
        {
            panel.ProgressBar.Value = (int)percentage;
        }

        strm.Write(buff, 0, buffLength);
        contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);
        uploadLength += (contentLen + 0.0) / 1024 / 1024;
    }
    strm.Close();
    fs.Close();
}
```

It works well with the function of pause and continuation.
But when the network interrupts, all this stream will not be writen to the ftp server.
I think it only write to the ftp server when you call "strm.Close()"

How could I realize the funtion that when the network interrupts, this file stream will be writen on the ftp server?
(Maybe I can save or close the stream when I upload every 10MB data)
Thank you!

Comment: "How could I realize the funtion that when the network interrupts, this file stream will be writen on the ftp server? (Maybe I can save or close the stream when I upload every 10MB data)"
- What about strm.Flush()?